# LLVM non local memory dependency analyis

Tags: c++, llvm

I am writing a LLVM pass which needs to analyse memory dependencies. The pass needs to find for a memory read every instruction that could have defined this memory. For example:

```
int foo(){
   int x = 123;

   if(getchar()){
        x = 321;
   }

   return x;
}
```

In this case the pass needs to find both definitions of x when it loads x from memory on the return. I used the following code in my pass.

```
MemoryDependenceAnalysis &MDA = getAnalysis<MemoryDependenceAnalysis>();

if (isa<LoadInst>(i)) {
    MemDepResult d = MDA.getDependency(&i);

    if (d.isNonLocal()) {
        SmallVector<NonLocalDepResult, 4> result;
        MDA.getNonLocalPointerDependency(&i, result);

        for (SmallVectorImpl<NonLocalDepResult>::iterator it=result.begin() ; it < result.end(); it++ ) {
            MemDepResult dd = it->getResult();

            if (dd.isUnknown())
                errs() << "Unknown\n"; //result always unknown
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MDA.getDependency() gives me the right results for dependencies that a local (in the same basic block). But getNonLocalPointerDependency() always return null pointers.

How do I get LLVM to find every store that could have defined the memory of a load instruction?

Comment: I complied your example to LLVM IR and this is transformed into load STDIN, getc, cmp, select, return.  Variables, such as x in your example, are often just SSA values and not actual memory locations.

Comment: I compiled it without optimizations and I got alloca, load and 2* store. This example was given to illustrate a case where multiple stores depend on one load.